# MYSQL INSERT INTO TABLE WITH SELECT

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to execute the below insert in MYSQL but it fails.

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_A(M_DATE,T_M_ID,I_M_ID)
(
    '2015-05-16',
    SELECT T_ID FROM TWD WHERE T_NAME = 'abc',
    SELECT I_ID FROM IWD WHERE I_NAME = 'dfgh34sd78'
);
```

The table TABLE_A also has an auto increment M_ID field

Any ideas on how to fix this ons please?

```
ERROR

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''2015-05-16',
      SELECT T_ID FROM TWD WHERE T_NAME = 'abc',
' at line 3
```

Comment: what do you want to do?

Comment: Start by posting the error message that MySQL is giving you. Read it first - you might fix the problem yourself.

Comment: I've tried building the query using SET a well. I've run the individual SELECT queries to ensure results are returned. The problem is when I run it with an INSERT.

Comment: Did you even read the comments above yours? ;-)

Comment: Hello dhh - Yes I did. I've posted the error message. I've done some digging before posting a question here. I'm not trying to be lazy & get someone to solve my problem without putting some efforts to understanding it. Any help would be much appreciated. So far, I've tried inserting hard coded values into the table & it works. It's with the SELECT + INSERT that am having a problem. The SELECT alone runs fine. So there obviously is a mistake int he syntax I take. I haven't been able to work out myself & hence requesting assistance.

Comment: Hello Sinhayash - I'm trying to insert date, an T_ID for a T_NAME which I select from table TWD & I_ID for a I_NAME which I select from table IWD. I'm open to a different way of doing this too. I'd appreciate any help please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have ended up moving all of those new lines into one single one & use `SET.` It's working. Here's what is working for me.

```
INSERT INTO `TABLE_A` SET M_DATE = '2015-05-16', T_M_ID = (SELECT T_ID FROM TWD WHERE T_NAME='abc'),I_M_ID  = (SELECT I_ID FROM IWD WHERE I_NAME='dfgh34sd78');
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you try with below:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_A (M_DATE,T_M_ID,I_M_ID) VALUES
(
    '2015-05-16',
    (SELECT T_ID FROM TWD WHERE T_NAME = 'abc' LIMIT 1),
    (SELECT I_ID FROM IWD WHERE I_NAME = 'dfgh34sd78' LIMIT 1)
);
```

Comment: Hello Arpit - No doesn't help. THankyou for trying.

Comment: I'm working out a different way of doing this. Tried quotes, INSERT TO TABLE VALUES, SET .. None of these seem to help.